# Как перехватить запрос

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

PHP

```
  if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'joined'){

                        echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Вы зарегестрированы, проверьте почту и активируйте аккаунт</h2>";

                }
```

js:

```
   function register()

$.post( "/index.php",{'username': $('#user').val(),'email' : $('#emailr').val(), 'password' : $('#passwordr').val(),'passwordConfirm' : $('#password_confirmation').val(), 'submit' :'Register', 'g-recaptcha-response' : 'g-recaptcha-response',  },

     function( data ) {

            console.log( data );
            //alert( data );
             //$( ".error" ).append( data );
            if(data == 1){ 
            // $('#test').show(); 
             $("#err").html("Все ОК");


            } else {
                //$("#err").html("Компот");
                 error();  
                //return false; 

            }
            function error(){
    $('#loginModal .modal-dialog').addClass('shake');
             $('.error').addClass('alert alert-danger').html( data );
             //$('input[type="password"]').val('');
             setTimeout( function(){ 
                $('#loginModal .modal-dialog').removeClass('shake'); 
    }, 10 ); 
}
return ;
        });
```

Как преобразовать ответ joined в 1, или вывести в div?

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема в том что `ajax'ом` Вы отправляете `POST` запрос, а на сервере смотрите `GET` массив.

Вы показали не связанные куски кода. Код `PHP` не обрабатывает тот запрос который отправляет `JS`. Для более точного ответа, предоставьте код который обрабатывает ваш запрос.

Comment: приходит ответ action joined